# how to use Ajax to get content from JSON files dynamically in DART?

Tags: ajax, json, asynchronous, dart, angular-dart

I know how to use JSON in dart also communicating with a server using the HttpRequest API from the dart:html library and parsing JSON data using the dart:convert !!https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

I am looking for Dynamic content loading using **Ajax asynchronous methods or calls in DART!** ..

like .. the web page need to load content dynamically if there is any change or update in JSON files in server! ..

And how to do this in Angular Dart!?

Comment: What is the difference between loading JSON using HttpRequest and Ajax? You need a way to get notified about changes or to poll for changes, then you make a HTTP request to load the changes and then you modify the dom depending on the recieved data. Please add some more information about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I had a similar personal need as you in the past. I agree with @GünterZöchbauer that the underlining problem is to either poll or create a web socket depending on how frequently your data changes. For my personal problem I utilized DartForce for handling the communication. You can find an excellent screencast at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZr75CsBNag&list=PLq7yml7rGSYZtWaY_3QO7dwjS98X3OLIk and other documentation at https://github.com/ForceUniverse/dart-force.

Comment: A [BOSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH) approach may meet your  requirement, although I'm afraid don't know of a package that implements it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to be notified when something changes on the server without either a) polling for changes (this can be pretty wasteful) or b) having the server notify you.

For (a), you could create a [periodic timer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Timer#id_Timer-periodic) that fetches the JSON or checks whether it's been updated (you'd need some way of checking this with the server).

A better fit would be something like Web Sockets, with the server able to push your JSON to the client whenever it changes. However, this is quite an architecture change from pulling JSON from the server, because you would need to be holding web sockets open between the server and all clients that have the page loaded, so the server can send the data to them all whenever it changes.

There are some samples of using Web Sockets [on the Dart site](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Timer#id_Timer-periodic); but bear in mind you'll need something on the server, this won't work if you only have access to the client.

Comment: ya, now i started using websockets also i have server written for websocket and it works fine.